# How to use multiple join statements and also update?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created three tables such that

```
CREATE TABLE guest(

name varchar(100),
ranking int,
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE room(

 roomname varchar(100),
 wallcolor varchar(100),
 rating int,
 PRIMARY KEY(roomnane)
 );

 CREATE TABLE reservation(

 name varchar(100),
 roomname varchar(100),
 day varchar(100),
 moveinday int,
 moveoutday int,
 PRIMARY KEY(roomname, day, start, finish),
  FOREIGN KEY(roomname) REFERENCES room(roomname),
  FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES guest(name)
 );
```

The answer I am looking for is:

```
{LakeView, Monday, John, 10, 14, Reggie, 9, 11}
```

I am trying to formulate 2 queries

1. Find conflicting reservations where the same room is reserved in the same day for overlaping move-in and move-out times. i.e I am trying to output roomname, day, name1, start1, finish1, name2, start2, finish2.

I have tried

```
 select rr.roomname, rr.day, rr.name, rr.start, rr.finish, rr.name, rr.start, rr.finish  
 from room r, guest g, reservation rr
 join reservation r1 on room.roomname = r1.roomname 
 join reservation r2 on room.roomname = r2.roomname
```

I am not sure how to do the where clauses and get the correct input. Any help is appreciated.

2. Change all the "Queen" rooms to "King" and "King" rooms to "Red" without naming the boats involved. I am not sure how to use the update statement for this task. Again any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

This will be inserted into reservation

```
insert into reservation values ('Andy', 'LakeView', 'Monday', 10, 14);
insert into reservation values ('Andy', 'MarineView', 'Saturday', 14, 16);
insert into reservation values ('Andy', 'BayView', 'Wednesday', 8, 12);
```

Comment: Can you provide sample rows inserted into `reservation` table? I can't make out what you are storing in `day, moveinday, moveoutday` columns.

Comment: I edited the code question with some input

Comment: Again no data for the 2. question. Are "Queen", "King" the `roomname`'s?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT r1.roomname, r1.day, r1.name, r1.moveinday, r1.moveoutday, r2.name, r2.moveinday, r2.moveoutday
FROM reservation r1
INNER JOIN reservation r2
WHERE r1.roomname = r2.roomname AND
      r1.day = r2.day AND
      (
         r1.moveinday between r2.moveinday and r2.moveoutday OR
         r1.moveoutday between r2.moveinday and r2.moveoutday
      ) AND r1.name <> r2.name
```